# Is there a way to debug one page at a time and not the whole site?

Tags: asp.net, debugging

I am running into an issue when I go to debug my project. I am trying to debug one page at a time. I have set my start and endpoints to debug, and also set the page that I want to debug as the start page.

But when I go to run the debugger, I get errors from another page (that I don't need to debug yet).

Is there away to debug one page at a time?  Or do I have to debug the entire site?

Comment: Are you running into compile errors (code won't go into debug mode), or runtime errors (error happens while you are debugging)?  If you are hitting compile errors, you need to "fix" the code enough to get it to build, so that you can debug.  If you are running into runtime errors, update your question with the code that breaks at runtime and we can suggest a way of fixing it.

Comment: CWM, what errors are you getting?

Comment: Just some basic errors from other pages like...ASP.forms_frmfacilityassets_frmfacilityassets_aspx.GetTypeHashCode()': no suitable method found to override, which i have no idea what its about. But the other 3 errors are basic things that i can just comment out

Comment: Yeah, basically, comment out the stuff that doesn't work.  **But remember to go back and fix it**

Comment: @GarrisonNeely, thats what I'm probably going to do is comment out the errors and go back to fix them later, hopefully I don't get any other errors when I comment out the other errors

Comment: One minute it tells me that i have 4 errors, next thing you know i have 104 errors, then i rebuild the solution and i go back to 4 errors. Commenting out the original errors didn't help.

Comment: Clean the solution before building. Sometimes, Visual Studio must be restarted. If you're totally frustrated, reboot. Then Clean, then Rebuild. Then fix the errors - or show us the code that's causing the errors.

Answer (score 0):

A Web Application project is essentially compiled as a single entity.  Kind of like compiling an EXE.  So, yes, you need to solve all of your compilation errors before you can debug a single page.

So, you are going to have to tackle each compilation error before you can run your project.